# numberOfRowsInSection called before openWithCompletionHandler block

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
    [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

        self.list = [[Categories getArrayForFirstTable:self.document.managedObjectContext] mutableCopy];

    }];

 }
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.list count];
}
```

numberOfRowsInSection called befor openWithCompletionHandler's block.
[self.list count] is nil ,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openWithCompletionHandler` block is an asynchronous operation, according to [the apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDocument/openWithCompletionHandler%3a)

> You call this method to begin the sequence of method calls that opens and reads a document asynchronously. The method obtains the file-system location of the document from the fileURL property. After the open operation concludes, the code in completionHandler is executed.

So you `[self.tableView reloadData]` will be executed, which triggers `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, before your `self.list` getting a meaningful result through `self.list = [[Categories getArrayForFirstTable:self.document.managedObjectContext] mutableCopy];`

This code may meet your needs:

```
[self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    self.list = [[Categories getArrayForFirstTable:self.document.managedObjectContext] mutableCopy]; 
    // At this point(no matter when), self.list is returned and you can use it.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: If I wanna change the self.list, should I give up this block? have some solutions?